# Ruby: How to require and instantiate all the files in a directory?

Tags: ruby

I am developing a Gem that will allow users to auto-require, instantiate, and register classes in a specific directory. I'm just not sure how to achieve this. This is what I've come up with so far...

```
Dir[Dir.pwd + '/extensions/*.rb'].each do |file|
  require file
  extension_class = # instantiate the class here
  MyApp.extensions << extension_class
end
```

How can I instantiate the class without knowing what it is called?

Comment: The simplest solution is to name the file after the class. Then you can use the filename.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are making a system for writing extensions to software.  Since the extension classes are probably all similar in some way, such as sharing some common methods, it might make sense to have a base class called `Extension` from which all the extension classes inherit.

In fact, this is very useful to the stated problem because when a user inherits from your class you can detect it, and add the subclass to a list.  Here is some proof of concept code:

```
class Extension
  class << self
    attr_reader :list
  end
  @list = []

  def self.inherited(klass)
    @list << klass.new
  end
end

# The MyExt class would be in another file, loaded by require.
class MyExt < Extension
end

p Extension.list   # => [#<MyExt:0xb777d884>]
```

If you don't want to use subclassing for some reason, it is equally easy to make `Extension` be a module and use the `included` hook instead of `inherited`.

Personally, I would just remove the call to `.new` because I don't see a reason to instantiate the class right away, but that's up to you.  I would just store a list of classes.

Answer (score 1):

this is an interesting idea which had me scratching my head for a while. i couldn't find an immediate solution with googling, so i played around with the language a bit. i came up with three basic ideas:

- keep track of all loaded classes, and grab new ones as they come in
- use a naming scheme to relate filenames to classes
- use some sort of introspector on the required classes so they can register themselves for future inclusion

i decided that i liked the first option the most; it doesn't require you to structure your files in a particular way, or augment the classes in order to know they will be required this way. here is a rudimentary implementation, borrowing your initial structure:

```
classes = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a
Dir[Dir.pwd + '/extensions/*.rb'].each do |file|
  require file
  changed_classes = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a
  (changed_classes - classes).each do |extension_class|
    MyApp.extensions << extension_class
  end
  classes = changed_classes
end
```

Comment: This seems kind of bad because then every new class defined in the file gets registered as an "extension", making it impossible to have any helper classes.

Comment: Quite an elegant soulution! I like the diffing of `classes` and `changed_classes`. +1.

Comment: @DavidGrayson - i do agree. one can imagine coming up with some sort of convention to get around the problem, but it will end up being specific to the application. i would like to think of a cleaner, fourth way.

Comment: I would just use const_get(file_name.camelize). Also, using Dir.pwd isn't a good idea because it won't work if you launch the script from a different directory; I'd use File.expand_path("..", _FILE_).

Comment: the notion of using the filename was suggested in my answer, but it has its own drawbacks. i agree about pwd, probably should not have copied that idiom from the question.